# Saving numpy array to a binary file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I saved my numpy array to a binary file as `np.save("image_mean.npy", averaged_mean)`. When I open the file, observed the bianry file's header as `“NUMPY  V {'descr': '<f8', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (3L, 704L, 1248L), }`.

My query is what `NUMPY  V` refers to?
If I want it as `NUMPY F` `“NUMPY  F {'descr': '<f8', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (3L, 704L, 1248L), }`, how can I change in `np.save` API?

Comment: Why do you want `F`? What do you think that will change in the file format? I think that the `V` is referring to version myself. [Here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/npy-format.rst) is the documentation on .npy

Comment: If you're wanting to save a numpy array to a "raw" binary file, don't use `np.save`.  `numpy.save` will save the file in "npy" format, which is not a raw binary file (thus the header).  Instead, it has a header, etc. Instead, use `your_array.tofile(filename)`.  To change the order to a fortran ordered array, you'd use `your_array.ravel(order='F').tofile(filename)`.

Comment: documentation on .npy format is now at scipy.org  [numpy.lib.format](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`V` is the length of the header data (include space paddings and the terminating newline).

As given in [the documentation -](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/neps/npy-format.html#format-specification-version-1-0)

> 1. The first 6 bytes are a magic string: exactly “x93NUMPY”.
> 2. The next 1 byte is an unsigned byte: the major version number of the file format, e.g. x01.
> 3. The next 1 byte is an unsigned byte: the minor version number of the file format, e.g. x00. Note: the version of the file format is not tied to the version of the numpy package.
> 4. **The next 2 bytes form a little-endian unsigned short int: the length of the header data HEADER_LEN.**
> 5. The next HEADER_LEN bytes form the header data describing the array’s format. It is an ASCII string which contains a Python literal expression of a dictionary. **It is terminated by a newline (‘n’) and padded with spaces (‘x20’) to make the total length of the magic string + 4 + HEADER_LEN be evenly divisible by 16 for alignment purposes.**

The length of the header data from your example (including a single newline) comes to 71 . So that makes `magic_string + 4 + HEADER_LEN` equal `81` , which is not divisible by 16 , so the next divisible number is 96 , hence the header data is padded with 15 spaces so that that total length becomes equal to `96` . This makes the header length to be - `86` . Which is `V` .

```
>>> chr(86)
'V'
```